# How to set AppBuildDir - Error when running Code Analysis in Xamarin Studio

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm using Xamarin Studio for the Mac, version 6.2.

From the Project menu I select "**Run Code Analysis on Solution**".

### Error

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets:
Error: Error executing task CompileEntitlements: Required property 'AppBundleDir' not set.
(Core.iOS)

Core.iOS is an iOS project that the main project depends on.

I don't know where or how to set this "AppBundlerDir" and I can't find answers anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

`AppBundleDir` is a MSBuild property that represents an app bundle directory path. You can set this in your `.csproj` along the lines of

```
<AppBundleDir>$(DeviceSpecificOutputPath)$(_AppBundleName).app</AppBundleDir>
```

You should be able to get a general idea of what Tasks/Targets use it here:

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/blob/fc55e4306f79491fd269ca2495c6a859799cb1c6/msbuild/Xamarin.iOS.Tasks.Core/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets

You can find a definition of how it gets set here: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/blob/fc55e4306f79491fd269ca2495c6a859799cb1c6/msbuild/Xamarin.iOS.Tasks.Core/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets#L589

Comment: do you know where in the .csproj that xml above would go?

Comment: The weird thing is, I haven't been able to use your solution but Code Analysis mysteriously started to work. I handled some issues, committed the changes, ran Code Analysis again and the error came back. So strange.

Comment: This property should be given a value by default by looking at the targets. If you need to override it, you can really place it anywhere in your .csproj. Typically you want to do it in your configuration sections. i.e. in the Debug or Release configuration.

Comment: OK, this worked. The error for AppBundleDir went away. I found the <PropertyGroup>s for the different configurations and added it within. So you were saying <AppBundleDir> should have been in the *.csproj by default? Because I don't see it in any of our other projects and when I created a new project it wasn't in there either.

Comment: No, I believe it gets set from within the build process in a target!

Comment: So strange. Strange because this only happens when running Code Analysis and not building, debugging, publishing, etc.

Comment: So it sounds like a code analysis target isn't setting that value. It might be a bug you can report here! https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=iOS (However it might be third party)